# AlertDialog Not Displaying in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an Alert Dialog to reset password in Firebase. But the AlertDialog is not showing up.

I added print statement to check if the button works and it does work. But the Dialog is never displayed.

FYI, I am creating this in a Fragment Class.

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        System.out.println("SETTINGS PAGE OPENED!");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        passResetBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.passResetBtn);

        passResetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("CLICKED!");
                final EditText resetMail = new EditText(getContext());
                AlertDialog.Builder passResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                passResetDialog.setTitle("Reset Password");
                passResetDialog.setMessage("Enter Your Email To Receive The Reset Link");
                passResetDialog.setView(resetMail);

                passResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String email = resetMail.getText().toString();
                        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reset Link Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                passResetDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = passResetDialog.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this line over `return view;` statement

```
passResetDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your OnClick Event before closing the brackets add the follwoing line:

```
passResetDialog.show()
```

Without saying to dialog it has to show it wouldnt appear.

Reference :-
[Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#show())